# iOS PDFView on external display has blurry part

Tags: ios, swift

I followed this tutorial to output a PDFView to an external monitor via HDMI Adapter
http://tutorials.tinyappco.com/Swift/AdditionalScreen

The problem I'm encountering is that the PDF on the display has a blurry portion to it, as seen in the pictures [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNynk.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m472.jpg), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j37rZ.jpg). This happens to other PDF files. I have also tried using WKWebView to display the PDF and also has the same issue.

This blurry portion can also be seen when I run the app on the simulator with external display.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: no I have not found a solution for this